# Does this representation have a name?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$. Let $F(X) = \{f: X \to \mathbb C\}$ be the set of complex valued functions on $X$. This is a complex vector space.

Then $G$ acts on $F(X)$ linearly via the following operation:

$$ \pi (g) f(x) := f(g^{-1}x)$$

where $\pi : G \to (F(X)\to F(X))$ is the representation. Or at least that's what I gathered from the lecture.

Now my question is: does this representation have a name? The lecturer called it a ''quantization of a group action'' but when I tried to google that I found nothing.

Comment: There might be a more standard name for it, but this is basically the dual representation of $G\to\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and I would be comfortable referring to it as such.  You can even think of it rigorously as the dual of something, since the action of $G$ on $X$ induces a representation of $G$ on "$\mathbb{C}\otimes X$" $=\oplus_{x\in X} \mathbb{C} x$.

Comment: @Slade Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Left regular representation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation

Comment: @rafaelm: that only applies to the special case that $X = G$ with $G$ acting by left multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, the induced action on $\mathbb{C}[X]$, the free complex vector space on $X$, is called the *permutation representation* associated to the $G$-set $X$. The induced action on $\mathbb{C}^X$ is the dual of the permutation representation. When $X$ is finite, these two representations are isomorphic, but when $X$ is infinite they don't even have the same dimension in general. (When $X$ is infinite the dual representation is probably not what you're looking for, and you want to cut it down in some way.)

Understanding permutation representations reduces quickly to the case that $X$ is transitive, hence that $X = G/H$ for some subgroup $H$. Then $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ and $\mathbb{C}^{G/H}$ are two versions of the [induced representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation) $\text{Ind}_H^G(1)$, where $1$ is the trivial representation of $H$. When $H$ has finite index in $G$, these two representations are isomorphic, but again, in general the dual representation is probably not what you're looking for, and you want to cut it down in some way.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. So, $\mathbb C [X]$ and $F(X)$ are the same thing? It certainly sounds that way...

Comment: @self-learner: no; like I said, when $X$ is infinite $\mathbb{C}^X$ is much larger than $\mathbb{C}[X]$. People have a bad habit of failing to distinguish these constructions and I think it leads to confusion in the long run. Among other things, the assignment $X \mapsto \mathbb{C}[X]$ is a *covariant* functor in $X$, but the assignment $X \mapsto \mathbb{C}^X$ is a *contravariant* functor in $X$. The distinction between the two is a toy model of the distinction between homology and cohomology (and the fact that they are isomorphic when $X$ is finite is a toy model of Poincare duality).